# VBA Powerpoint How to know which shape is clicked during a presentation

Tags: vba, macros, powerpoint

In Powerpoint you can link a command button to a macro.

But in Powerpoint 2013 such a macro cannot have parameters;
In the popup list to link the button to a macro only subroutines without parameters are visible.

(in previous versions of powerpoint it was possible to link the button to something like 
Sub DoSomethingTo(oSh as Shape) where oSh was the shape that was clicked)

In the subroutine (macro) I want to know which shape was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

This still works in PPT 2013 and later but only for Public subroutines.  When you assign a macro as an action setting, you won't see any Private subroutines or any subs at all in modules that are private (ie, that have Option Private Module at the start).

Comment: I just found out that you CAN use a macro with parameters. The issue was that the list of macros shown when you click on the "Macro's" button does not contain these subroutines with paramers. When you click the Visual Basic button you can see the code of ALL subroutine.